# How would I take the average of the first column of a file every 6 lines with bash?

Tags: bash

I have a file that looks like this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat output.txt
 0.0 709312 gnome-session-b dan
 0.7 3662292  \_ gnome-shell dan
 0.0 1157420  \_ gnome-softw dan
 0.0 903172 gnome-shell-cal dan
 0.0 286580 gnome-keyring-d dan
 0.0 709312 gnome-session-b dan
 0.7 3662292  \_ gnome-shell dan
 0.0 1157420  \_ gnome-softw dan
 0.0 903172 gnome-shell-cal dan
 0.0 286580 gnome-keyring-d dan
 0.0 709312 gnome-session-b dan
 0.7 3662292  \_ gnome-shell dan
 0.0 1157420  \_ gnome-softw dan
 0.0 903172 gnome-shell-cal dan
 0.0 286580 gnome-keyring-d dan
 0.0 709312 gnome-session-b dan
 0.7 3662292  \_ gnome-shell dan
 0.0 1157420  \_ gnome-softw dan
 0.0 903172 gnome-shell-cal dan
 0.0 286580 gnome-keyring-d dan
 0.0 709312 gnome-session-b dan
 0.7 3662292  \_ gnome-shell dan
 0.0 1157420  \_ gnome-softw dan
 0.0 903172 gnome-shell-cal dan
 0.0 286580 gnome-keyring-d dan
 0.0 709312 gnome-session-b dan
 0.7 3662292  \_ gnome-shell dan
 0.0 1157420  \_ gnome-softw dan
 0.0 903172 gnome-shell-cal dan
 0.0 286580 gnome-keyring-d dan
```

How would I sort this and calculate the averages of the first 2 columns? I have a for loop that runs 6 times to populate this data so it would only have to calculate the averages every 6 lines.

Comment: bash is the wrong tool -- it has no built-in support for floating-point math. Use `awk` instead.

Comment: BTW, when you say "sort this" -- sort it *how*?

Comment: sort by name, the sort command works https://pastebin.com/V9VBfyUE

so now I need to take the averages of the first 2 columns every 6 lines

Comment: Pastebin is full of ads -- please use https://gist.github.com/, http://ix.io/, http://sprunge.us/ or another ad-free pastebin to be more polite to folks who don't use adblockers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash is the wrong tool -- it doesn't support floating-point math. Use `awk` instead:

```
awk '
# Initialization: Run once at startup
BEGIN {
  i=0;
  sum1=0;
  sum2=0;
}

# Run once per line
{
  sum1+=$1;
  sum2+=$2;
  if(++i >= 6) {
    print (sum1 / i) " " (sum2 / i);
    sum1=0;
    sum2=0;
    i=0;
  }
}

# Run once at the very end, for if our total number of lines was not divisible by 6
END {
  if(i > 0) {
    print (sum1 / i) " " (sum2 / i)
  }
}
'
```

Comment: I need it to read from a file.. I currently have something like this:

count=0;
total=0;

for i in $( awk '{ print $1; }' outputsorted.txt )
   do
     total=$(echo $total+$i | bc )
     ((count++))
   done
printf "Process Details for process $INPUT: \n"
ps -C $INPUT -o comm,user
printf "Average 30s CPU Usage: "
echo "scale=0; $total / $count" | bc

count2=0;
total2=0;

for i in $( awk '{ print $2; }' output.txt )
   do
     total2=$(echo $total+$i | bc )
     ((count++))
   done
printf "Average 30s MEM Usage: "
echo "scale=0; $total / $count" | bc

Comment: @DanM, you can pipe to the above from a file just fine (or redirect, as with `<filename`, *or* by putting the filename on the command line after the script).

Comment: BTW, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor -- and note that running `bc` once per line of input is *way* more expensive than starting `awk` just once and letting that single instance process the full input stream.

Comment: If I run "awk 'BEGIN { i=0; sum=0 } { ++i; sum+=$1; if(i >= 6) { print (sum / 6.0); sum=0; } }' < outputsorted.txt" I get a ton of results, I should only get 5 results.. https://pastebin.com/raw/iLPfwM6a

Comment: You can see my entire script here: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/K5aLKMnbNfuMgYX8WHxtBg

Comment: See recent edits -- original code wasn't resetting `i` when it reset `sum1` and `sum2`.

Comment: I'm trying to write a script for a code challenge and they are asking me to write a script as a substitute for top, so I'm using ps to output cpu and mem usage to a file and then calculating the averages based on that, so if you put in the word "gnome" it will give you the cpu averages over 30 seconds (check every 5). It works with pid numbers but now trying to get it to work with command names..

Comment: Frankly, how best to do that is not the question you asked, and it's not the question I'm answering.

Comment: (Several approaches come to mind -- one is to use `awk` arrays indexed by PID, with a sigil to be able to track polling invocations in which a given PID didn't exist at all... but that's well outside the scope of this question).

Comment: Thanks it is working,  but how do I make it the first column only?

Comment: Well I need to calculate the first column, print the average, then collect the average of the 2nd column then print the average, sorry I didn't specify this ealier

Comment: In my script I'm using '{ print $1; }' with awk but I'm not really sure where it fits in here, have you had a chance to look at it?

Comment: It's not part of your question, so I don't intend to look at it. You asked how to "calculate the averages of the first 2 columns" every 6 lines. I answered that question. If you *meant* to ask something different, start a new question.

Comment: Thanks I'll ask another question, this works for the time being